# Php remove html only tags

Tags: php, html, string

It's seems quite simple - `strip_tags($string);`

But I will repeat - **html** tags

With use of strip tags for example

```
"THIS<THISTHISTHIS" >> THIS
```

Or

```
$str = "You can write 'more' as < sign" >> "You can write 'more' as "
```

or

```
strip_tags("you know that 5<8"); //cuts '8'
```

and I dont want it.

I know that basicly `<everything>` can be tag in html, but I want to remove those default html tags

Answer (score 1):

So why don't use put the tags you want to keep in a string and call `strip_tags`

```
$keep = '<a><div><span>';
$new_html = strip_tags($html, $keep);
```

Comment: $keep = '<a><div><span>';echo strip_tags("you know that 5<8", $keep); cuts 8

Comment: So maybe add <8> to your whitelist?

Comment: you can htmlspecialchars your content using a dom parser first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) with a whitelist:

```
strip_tags($str,'<code><em><p>');
```

Alternatively, you could use an HTML parser like [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) one for removing the HTML tags.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could specify which tags you will allow in the second argument of strip_tags:

[string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check HTMLPurifier: http://htmlpurifier.org/

A bit hard in customization, but it gives very good filtering of html and css.